# inflight sockets in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, socket, unix-sockets

I was checking code of `sendmsg` system call for `AF_UNIX` socket, there I find one function: `wait_for_unix_gc` ( a garbage collector of inflight sockets).
Can anyone brief what these inflight sockets are?

Kernel File: [`linux/net/unix/garbage.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/plain/net/unix/garbage.c?id=refs/tags/v4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy from Unix network programming V1: Chapter 15.7

> The sending process builds a msghdr structure (Section 14.5)
>   containing the descriptor to be passed. POSIX specifies that the
>   descriptor be sent as ancillary data (the msg_control member of the
>   msghdr structure, Section 14.6), but older implementations use the
>   msg_accrights member. The sending process calls sendmsg to send the
>   descriptor across the Unix domain socket from Step 1. At this point,
>   we say that the descriptor is "**in flight**." Even if the sending process
>   **closes the descriptor** after calling sendmsg, **but before the receiving**
>   process calls recvmsg (in the next step), the descriptor **remains open**
>   for the receiving process. Sending a descriptor increments the
>   descriptor's reference count by one.

Comment: Is'nt it a description for in flight descriptor??? rather than in flight sockets... but anyway can we guess similar concept for in flight socket?? thanks for answering